# Comparar valores de elementos "input" com javascript ou jQuery

Tags: jquery

Galera, tentei fazer esse fiddle pra compreender como fazer comparações de condições de elementos com javascript, mas não sei que deu errado.

```js
var username = "admin";
var password = "admin";


function validarUsuarioSenha() {

  if ($("#usuario").value() == username && $("#senha").value() == password) {

    $("#loginCorreto").show();
  } else {

    $("#loginErrado").show();
  }

}
```

```css
#loginCorreto {
  width: 235px;
  height: 20px;
  background: green;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  display: none;
}
#loginErrado {
  width: 235px;
  height: 20px;
  background: red;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="usuario" type="text" placeholder="Digite seu login: " />
<br/>
<br/>
<input id="senha" type="password" placeholder="Digite sua senha: " />
<br/>
<br/>
<input type="button" value="Fazer login" onclick="validarUsuarioSenha()" />
<br/>
<br/>
<div id="loginCorreto">Login efetuado com sucesso!</div>
<div id="loginErrado">Usuário ou senha inválidos!</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utilize `$("elemento").val()` não `.value()`:

```js
var username = "admin";
var password = "admin";


function validarUsuarioSenha() {

  if ($("#usuario").val() == username && $("#senha").val() == password) {

    $("#loginCorreto").show();
    $("#loginErrado").hide();
  } else {
    $("#loginErrado").show();
    $("#loginCorreto").hide();
  }

}
```

```css
#loginCorreto {
  width: 235px;
  height: 20px;
  background: green;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  display: none;
}
#loginErrado {
  width: 235px;
  height: 20px;
  background: red;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="usuario" type="text" placeholder="Digite seu login: " />
<br/>
<br/>
<input id="senha" type="password" placeholder="Digite sua senha: " />
<br/>
<br/>
<input type="button" value="Fazer login" onclick="validarUsuarioSenha()" />
<br/>
<br/>
<div id="loginCorreto">Login efetuado com sucesso!</div>
<div id="loginErrado">Usuário ou senha inválidos!</div>
```

Comment: Deu certo amigo... Mas o que mudaste além do ".val()"?

Comment: A função `validarUsuarioSenha` deve ser declarada antes de ser referenciada no botão. Então inclua-a no <head> de preferência.

Answer (score 1):

Um elemento do DOM do tipo `input` têm uma propriedade `value`. Assim, usando JavaScript nativo pode saber-se o valor no momento usando `el.value`.

Quando usas jQuery corres uma função/método chamada `.val()`. O que o jQuery vai fazer é basicamente correr uma função para retornar a propriedade `value`. Daí os parenteses que invocam a função.
 Podia obter-se o mesmo usando `.prop(value)`.

Neste caso específico usar jQuery é desnecessário. O JavaScript nativo funciona igualmente em todos os Browsers.

Um exemplo seria:

```
var jVal = $('input').val();
var jProp = $('input').prop('value');
var nativo = document.querySelector('input').value;

console.log(jVal, jProp, nativo); // dá o mesmo em todos
```

**O teu código a funcionar:**

- usando JavaScript nativo: http://jsfiddle.net/nbtqhc9m/
- usando jQuery: http://jsfiddle.net/nbtqhc9m/1/